# Get Images from s3 bucket which was previously uploaded through domain xyz.com now I want to get images through abc.com domain how it is possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, cross-domain

I have s3 bucket which is mapped on xyz.com domain now I want to use the same bucket for abc.com domain and want to connect all images which are uploaded through xyz.com.

Is there any way to resolve this thing.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you referring to content in the bucket, and how have you mapped the domain to the bucket?

Comment: Didn't mapped the domain just created bucket and used in AWS instance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question. Could you please Edit your question and provide more details? For example, is the bucket named the same as the domain? How are you redirecting the domain to the bucket (eg using Route 53?). What do you mean by "uploaded through domain" and "get images through domain"? Please help us to help you!